# Send image with JSON message

Tags: php, json, base64

I have this code for sent image over json message:

```
$thumbnail = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/" . $current['username'] . "/picture");
$thumb_encoded = base64_encode($thumbnail);
$array = array();
$array['username']=$current_row['username'];
$array['image']=$thumb_encoded;
array_push($response['result'], $array);
```

but as i can see, received packet for each image is too big (as i read, base64 conversion add overhead). Because i need to send that JSON message to android app (and downloaded data size with mobile connection is a critical point for mobile devices) there's another way to sent image over json with less overhead possible?

Comment: send $thumbnail = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $current['username'] . "/picture"; directly

Comment: then on android app, how can i parse the image fields to obtain again a jpg image? Because JSON doesn't support image type

Comment: use $thumbnail in img tag this will display image

Comment: i don't need to show image on php. That script is only to get image from facebook, encode it and put inside an array ($response) that will be encoded in JSON and sent to an android app

Answer (score 0):

You could send the image as an image and put the username in the image name.